# Laws of motion and Forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, projectile, drag

Explain with the use of equations why a pistol fired from the clouds 10km away is capable of killing a person on the ground compared to when it is fired horizontally  over same distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When firing a pistol from the clouds the bullet travel with a constant acceleration of gravity. So when you have to calculate the final velocity of the bullet or the displacement

you can add this equation

s = ut + 1/2at^2

every second the velocity of the bullet increases 9.8m/s

But

When you shoot something horizontally it doesn't have an acceleration unless you power up the bullet like a rocket.

also, it will decrease the velocity over time because of the air resistance. (  when you shooting from the clouds it doesn't matter because of the acceleration.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the gun is held at $1m$ above the ground and as you said the man is $10Km$ away from the gun and the gun is fired horizontally .

[image]

The distance covered by the projectile when thrown horizontally with some velocity $u$ is given by the formula

$R = (u)(√\frac{2h}{g})$

For your question, $R =10 km = 10000m$ and let's take $h=1m $ and $g = 10 {/frac{m}{s^2}}$ .

Solving the above equation the required minimum velocity will be approx $22000 m/s^2 $ , which is much greater. The average speed of the bullets (which we use normally )is only $1200-1300 m/s$ . So for this to happen, your gun should be highly modified. Also the bullets will encounter the air resistance , so taking that into account the velocity of firing the bullets must be greater than what you got from the equation.

Now if it is fired from the clouds , it's velocity will keep on increasing throughout the path but not by the same amount since the value of **$g$ changes with height** but if you take it as a constant and solve for velocity  using the equation

$v = u +gt$

And time can be calculated using $S = ut +(1/2)gt^2$ , where$ S =10km$

you will notice that it is much faster and a small pebble falling with that speed can break your skull.
The value is also affected by the air resistance but it will be still a lot.

So the one fired from the clouds is a killer one.

Comment: @Chanda chewe was the answer helpful ?